# Mouseover losing focus when Ajaxing content in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal-7

I'm using an exposed filter in Drupal7 to filter items using ajax.

I have a menu with checkboxes to decide what is being filtered that is hidden until you hover over the menu category. This is all working fine until you select a checkbox.

The page filters correctly, but when the new content loads, the mouseover menu is loosing focus. I'm trying to keep the menu open when the new content is loading in, not sure what's wrong with my js.

```
$('.views-exposed-widget').live({
    mouseover:
        function()
        {
            $(this)
            .children('.views-widget')
            .addClass('show');
        },
    mouseout:
        function()
        {
            $(this)
            .children('.views-widget')
            .removeClass('show');
        }
});
```

** Edit: Removed .end(); Still loosing focus when content is loaded.

Comment: Does using `mouseente`r and `mouseleave` make a difference?

Comment: Why are you using the .end(); portion? Did you try removing those? According to the documentation, http://api.jquery.com/end/, this returns an element to it's previous state.

Comment: @epascarello using mouseenter and mouseleave do not make a difference. I actually had that originally and was hoping mouseover and out would fix it.

Comment: @MattK311 Honestly I was using the .end(); portion because I had originally used a fadeOut/fadeIn and it was suggested to me to use. I have however removed it and the problem remains.

Comment: Gotcha... How is the content being loaded? Into a div? Or does the whole page reload? Maybe put up some more code so we can see how it's loading. I'm not as familiar with Drupal7 so I might be at a disadvantage.